# Define conditional formatting formula in Exel outside of conditional formatting formula bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

It is possible to use a formula to determine which cells to format. I don't think the formula bar of the CF menu is very user friendly for editing formulae.

My current solution is to write / edit them in a normal cell on another sheet, and then copy each formula in the CF environment.

My question is how to indicate in that formula bar, that the formula is somewhere else.

=indirect(sheet2!g2) for example will not work.

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `"`

i tried it with `=INDIRECT("sheet2!$B$2")=3` and it worked perfectly...

however... the formula in your cell won't act dynamically. Having `A1` refering to `A2` and `B1` to `B2` won't work... you only can check the outcome of your formula... while just copy/pasting the formula souldn't be any problem